# Is the complex absolute value function real differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value

I am new to complex analysis and got completely confused about complex and real differentiability. I know that the complex absolute value function is nowhere complex-differentiable except at zero. But is the complex absolute value function real differentiable? If so, how could I prove this?

This just came up as I am supposed to show that the Wirtinger derivative of $ln |f(z)|$ is itself holomorphic, where f is a nowhere zero, holomorphic function on the open unit disk. I then asked myself why the Wirtinger derivative should even exist, i.e. why this composite is partially differentiable. I thought it could be easy to prove this saying that it is a composition of real-differentiable functions, but then exactly my problem occurred, as I do not know if real-differentiability also holds for $|.|$.

Comment: It does not have finite partial derivative at the origin.

Comment: Actually, the the complex absolute value function is nowhere complex-differentiable. This includes $0$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: And what about everywhere except the origin? In my example below f is nowhere zero, so could I say |f| is real-differentiable here?

Comment: It is real differentiable at all points except the origin.

Comment: Thank you! How would I compute the partial derivatives of $|z|$? I thought about doing it similarly to how it's done in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $||.||$, but is there an easier way?

Comment: $|z| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is differentiable with respect to $x$ and $y$ at all points except where $(x, y) = 0$.

Comment: After some calculations I arrived at $\frac{\partial ln ( |f(z)|)}{\partial z} = \frac{f'}{f}$. Since $f$ is holomorphic, so is $f'$ as well as $f'/f$ which proves the statement. Is my result correct?